# solr 6.5 with nutch 1.12

Tags: authentication, solr, web-crawler, nutch

Successfully connected nutch 1.12 with solr 6.5 and crawled the un-authenticated sites. While attempting to crawl authenticated sites, I cant proceed with it. Can anyone please help to overcome it.

**error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No form exists: user-login
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.resolveCredentials(Http.java:485)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.getResponse(Http.java:180)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase.getProtocolOutput(HttpBase.java:261)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:295)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No form exists: user-login
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.HttpFormAuthentication.getLoginFormParams(HttpFormAuthentication.java:183)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.HttpFormAuthentication.login(HttpFormAuthentication.java:95)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.resolveCredentials(Http.java:483)
```

**httpclient-auth.xml:**

```
 <auth-configuration>
    <credentials authMethod="formAuth"
            loginUrl="<url>"
            loginFormId="user-login" 
            loginRedirect="true">
    <loginPostData>
      <field name="name"
          value="*<name>*"/>
      <field name="pass"
          value="*<password>*"/>
      <field name="op"
          value="Log in"/>
    </loginPostData>
   </credentials>
</auth-configuration>
```

searched few links but couldn't solved.

Thanks.

Comment: In `$NUTCH_HOME/conf/nutch-site.xml` add `<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-elastic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value><description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
  include. 
  </description>
</property>` Ignore if already have, and reply

Comment: see your error logs for details !

Answer (score 0):

How do you identify the form that needs to be submitted? In the `httpclient-auth.xml` file you put the following:

```
loginFormId="user-login"
```

So the plugin it's trying to find the login form by id, meaning that the form must have the `user-login` id, change this value to the proper id of the form login in the webpage that you're trying to crawl.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge Luis , thats the error exactly we are facing.How to identify form id of a webpage using any post method.We tried using developer tools to use the form id, but is not working                                                                    `<form action="/user/login?destination=node/2793683" method="post" id="user-login" accept-charset="UTF-8">`